# Performing a segue after choosing a UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, xcode, segue

I have used segue, which should pass the index of cell that was pressed in my **TableView**, but the problem is that function **`didSelectRowAt`** runs after my segue. That sague was made by control dragging from a **custom cell** to another **view**.

Here is my code:

```
override  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    selectedScheduleN = indexPath.row
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "edit", sender: nil)
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch(segue.identifier ?? "") {
    case "edit" :
        print ("normal function")
        var dest : editScheduleViewController = segue.destination as! editScheduleViewController
        dest.x = selectedScheduleN
    case "add" : return

    default : return


    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Delete the segue you dragged from your `cell`. And add a segue from your `TableViewController` to `editScheduleViewController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not add the segue to the cell itself in `Storyboard`. Delete your existing segue and add a manual segue from your table view controller by ctrl dragging from the yellow `Navigation` icon on top of the view controller.
[image: Create manual segue]